# SharePoint 2010: How to display the list item id in CEWP on Display Form

Tags: 2010, cewp

On the display form, I have added a CEWP which has some text. I want to append the list item ID at the end of the text. How can this be done?

**Note:** Don't have access to SP Designer

Comment: you can write JSOM code in CEWP

Comment: Did you got it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one of the two scripts below in the source editor of the CEWP:

**To display the ID in the first row:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//
// Item ID in DispForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx
// Feedback and questions: Christophe@PathToSharePoint.com
//
function DisplayItemID()
{
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+"ID"+"=([^&#]*)");
var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
var TD1 = document.createElement("TD");
TD1.className = "ms-formlabel";
TD1.innerHTML = "<h3 class='ms-standardheader'>Issue ID</h3>";
var TD2 = document.createElement("TD");
TD2.className = "ms-formbody";
TD2.innerHTML = qs[1];
var IdRow = document.createElement("TR");
IdRow.appendChild(TD1);
IdRow.appendChild(TD2);
var ItemBody = GetSelectedElement(document.getElementById("idAttachmentsRow"),"TABLE").getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
ItemBody.insertBefore(IdRow,ItemBody.firstChild);
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("DisplayItemID");
</script>
```

**To display the ID in the last row:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//
// Item ID in DispForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx
// Feedback and questions: Christophe@PathToSharePoint.com
//
function DisplayItemID()
{
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+"ID"+"=([^&#]*)");
var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
var TD1 = document.createElement("TD");
TD1.className = "ms-formlabel";
TD1.innerHTML = "<h3 class='ms-standardheader'>Issue ID</h3>";
var TD2 = document.createElement("TD");
TD2.className = "ms-formbody";
TD2.innerHTML = qs[1];
var IdRow = document.createElement("TR");
IdRow.appendChild(TD1);
IdRow.appendChild(TD2);
var ItemBody = GetSelectedElement(document.getElementById("idAttachmentsRow"),"TABLE").getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
ItemBody.appendChild(IdRow);
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("DisplayItemID");
</script>
```